# How do I transfer stuff between characters?

Tags: the-division

The video ["Why you NEED a 2nd character"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iqs6WNKF9oc&feature=youtu.be) claims that you can transfer equipment between your own agent characters. But it doesn't really go into detail how.

Is it still possible to transfer items between your characters? I didn't see any obvious option to do that.

Comment: Is your stash shared between characters? That seems like the only method I can think of

Comment: Considering how you can't give your buddies stuff, I just assumed I couldn't give it to my other characters as well. Now I wish I hadn't sold all that stuff.

Comment: @twobugs: you're right. That actually works. If you'll write as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put items from your inventory into the stash, and then extract them from the stash on another character. This is currently the only way to transfer items between your own characters.

Comment: It would be a stretch to say it was the easiest... just the _only_ way to do so.

Comment: One of the things they've talked about is implementing a trading system, possibly in the upcoming April or May free content patches. I'm just future-proofing this answer a tiny bit.

Comment: @twobugs the "trading" system they're talking about will only allow you to drop the loot you've just picked up (there is very short time limit). That dropped loot will be available for pickup by others in your party. So it isn't really trading, more like sharing drops with rest of the party.

Comment: @vartec Ah, I missed that. Updated answer to reflect this being the only option.